# Two "Website" Namespaces?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Using ASP.NET 4.6 with WebForms.  Created a static class in App_Code called Settings:

```
public static class Settings
{
    // ... code ...
}
```

When trying to access from other static class also inside of App_Code folder get:

[image]

Also noticed I have two Website contexts:

[image]

Tried putting the Settings class inside the namespace "Website"; still have same issue.  Issue only resolves when I declare the class like:

```
internal static class Settings
{
    // ... code ...
}
```

I suspected I've done something wrong somewhere with namespaces; but I'm not sure what/where.  What is causing the solution two have two "Website" namespaces?

After further digging I found that there are two Website "Containers" - not namespaces.

References view by namespaces:

[image]

References view by "containers":

[image]

Still digging in to try to figure this out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Build Action' for the file itself was set to 'Content' instead of 'Compile'.  For some reason anytime I add a new class to the projects inside this solution they default to 'Content'.  Once I set to compile I was back down to a single 'Website' container and everything worked as it should.

[image: Build action]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have 2 website contexts, the drop-down list shows your "Currently Selected" context and your "Available" contexts. The namespace "Website" doesn't exist, that's simply your website project name.

When you find out what namespace your website is in (Intellisense should tell you if you create a new class in your website and hover over it.), simply surround your static properties in that same namespace.

An alternative is to define a new namespace to hold your static members then reference that namespace from your website.

Comment: Under the Settings class that cannot be referenced the dropdown has one option - "Website".  But in all of the other existing classes (that are working) the dropdown has two options "Website" and "Website" (see updated image above).

Comment: It looks like I have two Website "containers" - not namespaces; see edit above.